# Call non-default constructor for object in vector initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, vector, initialization, parameter-passing

I want to initialize a vector in an initialization list of a constructor. The vector consists of objects with a parameterized constructor. What I have is:

```
Class::Class() : 
   raster_(std::vector< std::vector<Cell> > (60, std::vector<Cell>(80)))
{
...
```

How can I call Cell::Cell with two parameters in the above line? The obvious:

```
raster_(std::vector< std::vector<Cell(true,true)> > (60, std::vector<Cell(true,true)>(80)))
```

didn't work.

Comment: Thoroughly confused.  Post the declarations for `Class` and `Cell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try :

```
Class::Class() : 
     raster_(60, std::vector<Cell>(80, Cell(true, true)))
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Note that I removed the useless `std::vector<std::vector<Cell> >` from the initializer. Also be aware that this could be highly ineffective depending on the cost of copying a `Cell` :

- It creates an `std::vector<Cell>` by copying 80 times the provided value `Cell(true, true)`
- It creates an `std::vector<std::vector<Cell> >` by copying 60 times the provided vector (which contains 80 elements itself) !

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could ommit the type. You say its highly ineffective. How am I supposed to initialize the array then?

Comment: @problemofficer: I guess it's fine as long as `Cell` is cheap to copy

Answer (score 1):

`:raster_(std::vector< std::vector<Cell> > (60, std::vector<Cell>(80, Cell(true, true))));`

if raster_ is something that takes the vector. If raster_ itself is the vector then like this

`:raster(60, std::vector<Cell>(80, Cell(true, true)))`